# How to Remove two consecutive double quotes from array after split

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I have a requirement where i will get the input from the user. He can enter

```
"features1,feature2",feature3,"feature4"
```

something like this. I'm using this

```
let arr: any = message.split(/,(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/)
```

to split the string and i'm getting result like

```
[""feature1,feature2"","feature3",""feature4""]
```

but i want the result like this

```
["feature1,feature2","feature3","feature4"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't thing what you're trying to achieve is possible only using `split` function.

After you split, loop over the error and replace `"` with `` (empty).

```js
const message = `"features1,feature2",feature3,"feature4"`;

let arr = message.split(/,(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/);

arr = arr.map(el=>el.replace(/"/g,''));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: one more requirement is i want to restrict user to enter above input only in textbox. if he enters "feature1","feature," i should show error for that

Comment: Sorry didn't get you. You want to restrict user on what basis?

Comment: for ex: if user enters ("Hello, this is a mistake", "I have forgotten one quote) this string then this logic will fail. So that want to restrict user there he forgot one quote.
some more scenarios where this logic won't work.

"Hello, this is a mistake", "I have forgotten one quote

, Hello, "This is my chance"
"Perfectly, done", ", I really like this one,", Very much
Gosh, you are good", "I am right, you are not"

Comment: You'll probably have to right a regex to test this, if it at all it is possible to right one. Or parse the string and check for your conditions

Comment: "Hello, this is a mistake", "I have forgotten one quote how can i show error for this string???